# Must I sanitize my inputs when using setter methods to populate a Doctrine Entity?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, sql-injection, sanitization

I am under impression that ORM uses some kind of sanitation technique, but I am not sure.  I looked at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html and was not clear on the issue.

**Question**

Will it be safe to use

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setModel($_POST['model']);
```

where POST is NOT sanitized previously, or must I always sanitize/validate my values first before sending them to Doctrine?

For reference

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * @var integer @Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     *      @Id @GeneratedValue
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $model;
}
```

Comment: Doctrine uses prepared statements and thus protects you against sql injections.  Still up to you to validate your data.

Answer (score 2):

You should always validate/sanitize user input. Even though Doctrine is using a prepared queries (which prevents SQL injections) you are not safe against other attacks.

Check this page, to see how to deal with inputs in Doctrine:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/security.html#user-input-and-doctrine-orm

Answer (score -3):

Your are right, Doctrine ORM is doing all the sanitization automatically. Therefore, as long as you are using ORM, you are **perfectly safe**.

So in your example no additional sanitization is required.

I would only say that instead of using raw $_POST array you are supposed to use the Request object that is automatically injected in your controller:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->setModel($request->get('model'));
```

Comment: thanks.  In my case I am using a raw $_POST as I do not have full framework support set up.  Just Doctrine + select library API.  Depending on framework used though your answer still stands.

Comment: I don't think you are "perfectly safe". You are safe against SQL injection attack only. It's not safe when you start using DQL. It's not safe when you expect a specific data type (number) and the user sends something else. - it will cause Exception.  The best practice says "never trust user" and always validate and sanitize user input.